# Как получить сообщение от user'a, которое он отправил в ответ на сообщение бота?

Tags: python, telegram

Имеется функция, срабатывающая на команду /command.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(<тут токен>)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def _command_(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите имя: ")
     ???
```

Как внутри функции получить сообщение от пользователя? То есть есть ли метод в каком-нибудь фреймворке (twx.botapi, telebot etc.), чтобы не через getUpdates костыльным способом получать сообщение?

Answer (score 1):

судя по всему хотели получить вот это:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def _command_(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите имя: ")
     bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_user)

def add_user(message):
    #тут функция записи в бд
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

В официальной доке по телеботу предлагают:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Если его падения обрабатывать (а падает он реже, но падает) то всё прекрасно работает.

Answer (score -1):

Получить имя пользователя можно гораздо проще :

- Первое имя - `message.from_user.first_name`
- Второе имя - `message.from_user.last_name`
- Псевдоним - `message.from_user.username`

Пример кода :

```
import telebot

token = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ' + str(message.from_user.username) + '!')
```

Comment: Тут вся суть не в самом имени, а в обработке ответного сообщения пользователя. А что касается имени, то оно может быть не конкретно данного юзера, а, в принципе, любого другого, например, для занесения в БД.

Answer (score -1):

Просто создаёшь функцию, которая получает сообщение. Этим сообщением ты можешь манипулировать как хочешь:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])

def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы написали: {0}".format(message.text))

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```